# how to remove a query arguments from all site urls?

Tags: php

I use url query arguments to display messages ether errors or info messages

for example i use `https://www.example.com?error=myerrormessagegoeshere`

or `https://www.example.com?success=mysuccessmessagegoeshere`

and i display the message but the problem is when i refresh the page the message will still appear because the query is still there so i need to remove that query from the url
i know that in wordpress

```
remove_query_arg( string|string[] $key, false|string $query = false )
```

is used for that but i cant have do what i want

thanks in advance .

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

i found this i think it's the right way
i used :

```
add_filter('removable_query_args', function($args) {
    array_push($args, 'my_custom_arg');
    return $args;
});
```

Comment: please correct me if i'm wrong